# Html entities in webview

Tags: android, html, character-encoding, android-webview

I have a String variable with this content:

```
<p>
    <strong>N&amp;aacute;plň pr&amp;aacute;ce</strong></p>
<ul>
    <li>
        Komunikace se z&amp;aacute;kazn&amp;iacute;ky (email, telefon) &amp;ndash; ře&amp;scaron;en&amp;iacute; dotazů, &amp;uacute;prav v objedn&amp;aacute;vk&amp;aacute;ch</li>
    <li>
        Spr&amp;aacute;va soci&amp;aacute;ln&amp;iacute;ch s&amp;iacute;t&amp;iacute; &amp;ndash; Facebook</li>
    <li>
        Pr&amp;aacute;ce s software &amp;ndash; Zendesk, Basecamp, intern&amp;iacute; software pro spr&amp;aacute;vu objedn&amp;aacute;vek</li>
    <li>
        Komunikace s dal&amp;scaron;&amp;iacute;mi členy t&amp;yacute;mu (logistika, marketing)</li>
    <li>
        Koordinace a za&amp;scaron;kolov&amp;aacute;n&amp;iacute; dal&amp;scaron;ich kolegyň ze z&amp;aacute;kaznick&amp;eacute;ho servisu</li>
    <li>
        Administrativn&amp;iacute; činnost podle aktu&amp;aacute;ln&amp;iacute; potřeby.</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to load this content in WebView like this:

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

But this did not work. WebView did not convert that html entities to normal character. I am also tried to load content with

```
mWebView.loadData();
```

but result was the same. Any solution?

Comment: have u enabled javascript...

Comment: I tried to enable it but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after long research I found Apache library that escapes/unescapes html entities. You can download it from `http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi`.

Then use it as follows:

```
String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(escaped);
```